# Como se interpreta este error Javascript?

Tags: javascript

***Teniendo el código:***

```
 function personalizedGreet(name)
    {
        var greet = function () { return hello + name; };
        var hello = "Hello ";  // Variable local definida después de la función anidada
       return greet;
    }


    //En otra parte del código...

    var greeting = personalizedGreet("Oscar");
    alert(greeting()); //Muestra en pantalla: Hello Oscar
```

Funciona correctamente, pero si comento el `return greet` , me dice `"TypeError: greeting is not a function` , ***porqué*** ?

*Lo que entiendo* es que al retornar `greet`, la variable `greeting` guarda la funcion interna que es `greet`, pero si no lo retorno me dice que `greeting` *no es una función* y mi problema de este entendimiento es:
Al ser este mi entendimiento yo pienso que si no lo retorno, la variable `greeting` ***guardaria la función*** `personalizedGreet(name)` y ***seguiría siendo una función*** solamente que ***sin hacer nada*** de lo que hace greet() , pero **entonces como funciona**?

Comment: si no retornas `greet` ni otra cosa, retornas `undefined`.  si retornas `undefined` entonces `greeting` sera `undefined`. esto es todo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dejando tu código como está sin comentar `return greet` tu variable `greeting`se convierte en una función de esta manera:

```
var greeting = function () { return hello + name; };
```

Esto es porque tu función `personalizedGreet()` devuelve esta misma función, eso lo podemos ver en este snippet.

```js
 function personalizedGreet(name)
    {
        var greet = function () { return hello + name; };
        var hello = "Hello ";  // Variable local definida después de la función anidada
       return greet;
    }


    //En otra parte del código...

    var greeting = personalizedGreet("Oscar");
    console.log(greeting);
```

Ahora si comentas el `return` tu función personalizedGreet no devuelve nada, y tu variable `greeting` ya no es una función como la quieres mandar llamar en tu código.

```js
function personalizedGreet(name)
    {
        var greet = function () { return hello + name; };
        var hello = "Hello ";  // Variable local definida después de la función anidada
       //return greet;
    }


    //En otra parte del código...

    var greeting = personalizedGreet("Oscar");
    console.log(greeting);
```

Simplemente es una variable que no tienen ningún valor asignado y te devuelve ese error.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que la function `personalizedGreet(name)` no devuelve nada, el valor de greeting es `undefined`, por lo que te da el error de `greeting is not a function` , ya que es `undefined` -> `undefined is not a function`

En javascript si no le especificas el valor de retorno a una funcion devuele por defecto undefined.personalizedGreet(name) no devuelve nada, por lo que greeting no es una funcion, es undefined,

Answer (score 0):

Tu mismo te has respondido, si quitas el return de la funcion personalizedGreet, sencillamente es una funcion que define 2 variables y al no tener un retorno cuando la asignas a greeting, no hay un dato para enviar al alert();

Es por esta razón que te da el error en alert(greeting());